# php: massive assignement

Tags: php

I want to do a massive assignement of my protected vars, i used this code:

```
protected $_productName = '';
protected $_price = 0;
protected $_categoyId = 0;  
 public function setAttributes($attributes)  
 {  
  foreach($attributes as $key => $val)  
  {
    $var = '_' . $key;
    $this->$var = $val;  
  }  
 }
```

`$attributes = array('productName'=>'some Product', 'price' => 10, 'categoryId' => 5)` for exapmle.

the code above works for me but I feel that it's not clean. Is there any better solution to do that?

thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is clean, nothing bad about it. You could maybe additionally see if class field exists before setting it - so you could assure you are not setting any additional fields, which are not defined in a class.

Also to make the code a little shorter, you could do:

```
$this->{"_{$key}"} = $val;
```

This is matter of taste what you like - your variant is fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is fine. I would add a check for the property:

```
foreach($attributes as $key => $val)  
{
    $var = '_' . $key;
    if (property_exists($this, $var)) 
    {
        $this->$var = $val;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much as a clean as it gets for mass-assignment.  There are alternatives, like using [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) instead of a `foreach` loop, but I find loops to be cleaner and easier to understand quickly in situations like these.

Answer (score 0):

it looks ok to me, but if $attributes is always an array probably you should add this to avoid errors

```
public function setAttributes($attributes=array())
```

doing that you won't receive a error if attributes is empty because initialize the $attributes array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). Assign array as property value. And for every time you call variable like `$this->var` invoke `__get` method

```
public function setAttributes($attributes)  
{  
   $this->attributes = $attributes;
}

function __get($var) {
  if(isset($this->attributes[$var])) return $this->attributes[$var];
  return false;
}

function __set($key, $var) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used something like the following code awhile ago as a test:

```
    private $data = array();

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data))
        {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->data[trim($name)] = trim($value);
    }
```